# Creating batches from the poll records in kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have a requirement to perform bulk writes to elasticsearch. We would like to know if there is a better way of batching the data and avoid data loss while doing the batching

```
 public void consume() {
        logger.debug("raw consume......");

        String topic = "json.incoming";
        String consGroup = "rConsumerGroup";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "20000");
        props.put("max.poll.records", "10000");

        consumer = new GenericConsumer<String, JsonNode>().initialize(topic, consGroup, STREAMSERDE.STRINGDESER, STREAMSERDE.JSONDESER, props);
        logger.debug("Kafka Consumer Initialized......");
        buffer = new ArrayList<MessageVO>();

        while (true) {
            try {
                ConsumerRecords<String, JsonNode> records = consumer.poll(100);
                Date startTime = Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTime();
                if (records.count() == 0 && !buffer.isEmpty()) {
                    lastSeenZeroPollCounter++;
                }
                if (records.count() > 0) {
                    logger.debug(">>records count = " + records.count());
                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, JsonNode> record : records) {
                        logger.debug("record.offset() = " + record.offset() + " : record.key() = " + record.key());
                        JsonNode jsonMessage = record.value();
                        logger.debug("incoming Message = " + jsonMessage);
                        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        MessageVO rawMessage = objectMapper.convertValue(jsonMessage, MessageVO.class);
                        logger.info("Size of the buffer is " + buffer.size());
                        buffer.add(rawMessage);
                    }
                    Date endTime = Calendar.getInstance()
                        .getTime();
                    long durationInMilliSec = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
                    logger.debug("Number of Records:: " + records.count() + " Time took to process poll :: " + durationInMilliSec);
                }
                if ((buffer.size() >= 1000 && buffer.size() <= 3000) || (buffer.size() > 0 && lastSeenZeroPollCounter >= 3000)) {
                    lastSeenZeroPollCounter = 0;
                    List<RawSyslogMessageVO> clonedBuffer = deepCopy(buffer);
                    logger.info("The size of clonedBuffer is ::: " + clonedBuffer.size());
                    writerService.writeRaw(clonedBuffer);
                    buffer.clear();
                }

                consumer.commitSync();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                logger.error("Error occured while processing message", throwable);
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Code to clone the data to avoid the data loss

```
 private List<MessageVO> deepCopy(List<MessageVO> messages) {
        List<MessageVO> listOfMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        logger.debug("DeepClone :: listOfMessages size ::: " + listOfMessages.size());
        listOfMessages.addAll(messages);
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(messages);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A better way than writing it yourself is to use the Kafka Connect API of Apache Kafka—it's been built specifically for streaming integration from systems into Kafka, and Kafka out to other systems :-)

The [Elasticsearch connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html) will stream data from a Kafka topic to Elasticsearch, with configurable batch sizes etc, as well as exactly-once delivery semantics, scalable processing, and so on.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*

Answer (score 0):

We handled the same usecase by simplifying the design of the application a little bit: We basically perform the following steps

1. Use Spring Kafka `BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener` for fetching
       records with `max.poll.records` set according to requirements
2. For each fetch, commit messages using Elasticsearch BulkRequest API
3. After successful bulk indexing, acknowledge to Kafka.
4. On failure retry or handle error

By following this simpler design, we appreciate that most of the bulk commits will have desired number of records. For the case when Kafka topic does not have as many messages as the desired number of records for bulk indexing, we decide to index whatever available in a single fetch in any case instead of explicitly handling the commit state, managing buffer etc. in the application.

Elasticsearch bulk commit is an optimization -- I do not find any reason to be extremely precise about the total number of records per single bulk request. (see [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html) as well).

P.S: We needed to write code instead of using connector or readymade solutions because our inputs are from multiple topics in different formats such as protobuf, zipped XML, Json etc. and we needed to do format conversion and complex deserialization before indexing the data